# Is there MFA AWS s3 sdk for java?

Tags: java, amazon-s3, sdk, aws-sdk

I’m writing this post to ask for a assistance with AWS s3 sdk. I can’t find any example of how to approach with MFA and java sdk. In the web console I’m using security token for login then switching role. In the terminal using saml2aws for credentials for one hour. And Not sure how to approach?

Answer (score 1):

The Java SDK for AWS supports temporary credentials obtained from the Security Token Service. They can be stored, for example, in your `.aws/credentials` file or as environment variables.

You can obtain temporary credentials using a long-term aws_access_key_id/aws_secret_access_key pair and the AWS CLI. For example:

My `.aws/credentials` file looks like this:

```sh
[long-term]
aws_access_key_id=<VALID_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID>
aws_secret_access_key=<VALID=_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY>
```

And I obtain a new set of temporary credentials by running:

```sh
$ aws sts get-session-token --profile long-term --serial-number <MFA_DEVICE_ARN> --token-code <MFA_TOKEN>
```